# jQuery drag and drop auto align

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have ten `<div>` in my HTML page which are displaying as boxes. I used `$(".first").draggable();` to make them as draggable. Now the scenario is, When dragging and dropping one `<div>` element, other div elements should auto align automatically. i.e. no `<div>` element should over lap. Could you guide me...

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI sortable gives the exact thing we need.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
<div class="demo">
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- End demo -->
<div class="demo-description">
<p>
    To arrange sortable items as a grid, give them identical dimensions and
    float them using CSS.
</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Its taken from [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) demo.